# Posting Credentials to a basic authorization site and opening the link in a new browser. Open URL instead of a response

Tags: c#, asp.net

The below code will post a request to an IIS basic authorization site.  And sucessfully log in to the site using Windows Credentials.  But what I need to do is convert this to opening the website in a browser much like opening a new hyperlink with a target="null".

So just a recap, how do you post the WebRequest to a new browser tab?  Or how do you send the CredentialCache to a new URL request?

```
 var request = WebRequest.Create(testURL);
    SetBasicAuthHeader(request, "username", "password", testURL);

    var response = request.GetResponse();

}

public void SetBasicAuthHeader(WebRequest request, String userName, String userPassword, String testURL)
{

    CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
    credentialCache.Add(new System.Uri(testURL), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(userName, userPassword, "domain"));
    request.Credentials = credentialCache;
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;

}
```

Comment: The headers should come from the clien request and there is no way to do such thing with simple links. What you might try is use jQuery or something similar and issue a GET with the custom authorization headers, but in this case you would have to send the credentials down to the client and this might be a security problem.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you can't send a response to a new tab.  The problem with what you are trying to do is that the request / response that you build on the server is technically the server's...not the client.  So even if you build the request and redirect the user to the URL you just authenticated to, the client is still considered unauthenticated because the authentication took effect on the server.